# Detecting if two objects are close to each other

Tags: wireless, detection

I am an electronics beginner but want to make two devices that can detect if they are near each other.

So if the devices enter a radius of less than 2 meters of each other they will both trigger an audible alarm

I need the devices to be **as small as possible**, i would use the term "micro" even, and be able to be recharged or even that fancy "wireless" recharging. The devices only need to be active for at least 5 days or longer

Thank you

Comment: Do they have line of sight between them? Are they fixed in orientation?

Comment: @OliGlaser - Not Always line of sight and orientation could change.

Comment: @Peterj - Actually it must be under 2M.

Answer (score 1):

Could an Arduino Near Field Communication (NFC) shield do the job?  Or a RFID shield.
As an example: [NFC Shield V2.0 of Seeed](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/NFC_Shield_V2.0)
But there must be other once in the market.

Comment: Thanks but WAY to big :-) Needs to be smaller than 1/4 of a credit card i think